# ListView Translate Animation Within relative layout, Listview not shown fully when the animation is done

Tags: android, android-listview, translate-animation

I have a relative raletive layout, in that layout I have an imageview and below that is the listview. I also have a button outside this layout. When I click on the button, then the listview animation should start from its position and it should cover the relative layout.
But the listview elements are not shown fully when the animation is in progress.

The layout file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/clickme" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">


        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:background="@drawable/jaguar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"/>




            <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.